# Evaluating $\sum_{k=1}^n k^x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finite Sum of Power?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155166/finite-sum-of-power)

Is there a general expression for $\sum_{k=1}^n k^x$ for any integer value of $x$? The table for $x=1,2,\dots 10$ is given [here](http://math2.org/math/expansion/power.htm). Is there formula for any value of $x$?

Comment: This seems to be the same question as [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155166/finite-sum-of-power).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For arbitrary natural $x\in\mathbb{N}$, the general formula is given by [Faulhaber's Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula), which is
$$\sum_{k=1}^n k^x = \frac{1}{x+1} \sum_{i=0}^x (-1)^i{x+1 \choose i} B_i \cdot n^{x+1-i}$$
where $B_i$ are the [Bernoulli Numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number) with $B_1 = -\frac{1}{2}$.

I am not too convinced that there exists a nice closed form expression for arbitrary $x$.

Comment: that's more scarier :(( ... is there any formula without summation?

Comment: @testuser If there is one, then I don't know about it. But I really doubt that there exists anything much nicer than this expression. You can already see in the list you provided that the expressions are getting quite large by the $10$ sum. This is simply a more compact way of expressing the inevitably larger sums that occur with higher powers.

Comment: perhaps so ... thank you for answer

Comment: Technically there is a "formula" without summation using the Bernoulli polynomials, specifically $$\sum_{k=0}^{x} k^p = \frac{B_{p+1}(x+1)-B_{p+1}(0)}{p+1},$$ but in some sense that is cheating, because the Bernoulli polynomial by definition is just  the above sum!

Comment: @testuser Of course the right-hand-side is related to Bernoulli polynomials $$ \sum_{k=1}^n k^m = \frac{1}{m+1} \left(B_{m+1}(n+1)-B_{m+1}(1)\right)$$

Comment: Also the sum defines what is known as [generalized harmonic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Generalized_harmonic_numbers): $$ \sum_{k=1}^n k^m = H_n^{(-m)} $$ This is somewhat a tautology, though.

Comment: Waaw ... I didn't know that

Comment: @Sasha: You can probably also use the Hurwitz zeta function and the zeta function, but that again is somewhat tautological.

Answer (score 2):

I already answered a question similar to this on this website. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186277/existence-of-smooth-function-fx-satisfying-partial-summation). You can use the zeta function and the Hurwitz zeta function to get a closed form formula to your sum,

$$ \sum_{k=1}^n k^x = \zeta(-x) + \zeta(-x,n+1) \,. $$

See [reference 1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) and [reference 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function).

Comment: Funny how that analytic continuation stuff works here.  ;)