# Proof for $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n k^a$ equaling a sum of fractions

Tags: summation, fractions, exponentiation

I know $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n k^2$ equals $n/6+n^2/2+n^3/3$, but... why?

And I also know that $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n k^3$ equals $n^2/4+n^3/2+n^4/4$, but... is there a pattern so I can easily get $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n k^a$? And could you give me a proof if so?

Comment: http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Sum_of_Sequence_of_Squares#Proof_1

Comment: If you want to have an investigate yourself about a general formula, I would recommend looking at Q$2$ of the $2008$ STEP III paper: http://www.admissionstestingservice.org/Images/7921-step-specification.zip

Comment: @snarski Thanks! I didn't know of that page!

Comment: You can generalize this [technique](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320985/how-to-determine-equation-for-sum-k-1n-k3/321000#321000) easily.

Comment: You may be interested in a [closed form](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186277/existence-of-smooth-function-fx-satisfying-partial-summation) in terms of the zeta function and the hurwitz zeta function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that we know the expression of
$$\sum_{k=1}^n k,\sum_{k=1}^n k^2,\ldots,\sum_{k=1}^n k^{p-1}$$
then since by telescoping
$$\sum_{k=1}^n (k+1)^{p+1}-k^{p+1}=(n+1)^{p+1}-1$$
and 
$$(k+1)^{p+1}-k^{p+1}=\sum_{s=0}^{p}{p+1\choose s}k^s$$
hence we can find 
$$\sum_{k=1}^n k^{p}=\frac{1}{p+1}\left((n+1)^{p+1}-\sum_{s=0}^{p-1}{p+1\choose s}\sum_{k=1}^nk^s-1\right)$$

Comment: Can ε be any number?

Answer (score 0):

In general, the formula for $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^a$$ (for $a\in\mathbb{N}$) will be a polynomial in $n$ of degree $a+1$. This polynomial will thus have $a+2$ coefficients, which you can solve for simultaneously by setting up a system of $a+2$ equations. For the case a=2:

$$\sum_{k=1}^nk^2=an^3+bn^2+cn+d$$

Now compute S, the sum, for 4 values of n:
$$n=1\implies S_1=a+b+c+d=1
\\n=2\implies S_2=8a+4b+2c+d=5
\\n=3\implies S_3=27a+9b+3c+d=14
\\n=4\implies S_4=64a+16b+4c+d=30
$$

So the problem is reduced to solving a system of four linear equations in four unknowns. MATLAB gives $$[\frac13, \frac12,\frac16,0]^T$$
as the solution.

In fact, I just noticed that 'd' will always be 0 so you can do this with only 3 (a+1) equations instead of 4 (a+2).